# Changing Default Values of Percona Audit Log

Tags: mysql-5.5, audit, percona-tools

Have I missed Something here? I am installing the Percona Audit Log Plugin (MySQL 5.5).

I can install it fine using:

```
INSTALL PLUGIN audit_log SONAME 'audit_log.so';
```

I can then see all the default variables with:

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'audit%';
```

Looking at the documentation it tells me that for the most part they are not Dynamic.

So how do I set them to what I need at the time I install the plugin?
From what I can tell the only option is to add them to my `my.cnf` file and restart the Database.

That's fine for a Test System, but I can't go round restarting my LIVE databases, just to install a plugin, surely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a handful of options that are Dynamic, but for the most part they have to be added to the cnf file, which means you need to restart your live databases if you want to use it.

Comment: https://www.percona.com/blog/2015/09/10/percona-server-audit-log-plugin-best-practices/ - This says that if you add the configuration to your my.cnf file, and Then install the plugin, it will re-read the my.cnf file, and thus get the configuration that you want.